# Windows NT Service shutdown issues

Tags: c#, windows-services, middleware, system-shutdown

I have developed middleware that provides RPC functionality to multiple client applications on multiple platforms within our organization.  The middleware is written in C# and runs as a Windows NT Service.  It handles things like file access to network shares, database access, etc.  The middleware is hosted on two high end systems running Windows Server 2008.

When one of our server administrators goes to reboot the machine, primarily to do Windows Updates, there are serious problems with how the system behaves in regards to my NT Service.  My service is designed to immediately stop listening for new connections, immediately start refusing new requests on existing connections, and otherwise shut down as rapidly as possible in the case of an OnStop or OnShutdown request from the SCM.  Still, to maintain system integrity, operations that are currently in progress are allowed to continue for a reasonable time.  Usually the server shuts down inside of 30 seconds (when the service is manually stopped for example).  However, when the system is instructed to restart, my service immediately loses access to network drives and UNC paths, causing data integrity problems for any open files and partial writes to those locations.  My service does list Workstation (and thus SMB Redirector) as a dependency, so I would think that my service would need to be stopped prior to Workstation/Redirector being stopped if Windows were honoring those dependencies.

Basically, my application is forced to crash and burn, failing remote procedure calls and eventually being forced to terminate by the operating system after a timeout period has elapsed (seems to be on the order of 20-30 seconds).

Unlike a Windows application, my Windows NT Service doesn't seem to have any power to stop a system shutdown in progress, delay the system shutdown, or even just the opportunity to save out any pending network share disk writes before being forcibly disconnected and shutdown.  How is an NT Service developer supposed to have any kind of application integrity in this environment?  Why is it that Forms Applications get all of the opportunity to finish their business prior to shutdown, while services seem to get no such benefits?

I have tried:

Calling SetProcessShutdownParameters via p/invoke to try to notify my application of the shutdown sooner to avoid Redirector shutting down before I do.

Calling ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime with a value less than or equal to the two minute limit.

Tweaking the WaitToKillServiceTimeout

Everything I can think of to make my service shutdown faster.

But in the end, I still get ~30 seconds of problematic time in which my service doesn't even seem to have been notified of an OnShutdown event yet, but requests are failing due to redirector no longer servicing my network share requests.

How is this issue meant to be resolved?  What can I do to delay or stop the shutdown, or at least be allowed to shut down my active tasks without Redirector services disappearing out from under me?  I can understand what Microsoft is trying to do to prevent services from dragging their feet and showing shutdowns, but that seems like a great goal for Windows client operating systems, not for servers.  I don't want my servers to shutdown fast, I want operational integrity and graceful shutdowns.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

UPDATE: I've done the exact timings.  In a test shutdown, I got shutdown notification at 23:55:58 and noticed losing network share connectivity at 23:56:02.  So within four seconds, I've lost the ability to save out any active state.

Comment: Not an answer to your question really, but what about all the other failure modes, like a router crashing, or the remote fileserver suddenly rebooting? Don't you have to deal with all of those anyway?

Comment: Maybe adding Netman to your dependencies in addition to Workstation is worth a try.

Comment: On the front end, I run multiple copies of this middleware service, on multiple blade servers, with a highly available redundant pair of F5 load balancers in front of them, configured for reselect with tight timings.  Our network is designed for redundancy using HSRP for the routers (layer 3 switch interfaces mostly), LACP for the trunks between switches, etc.  The primary fileserver I'm concerned about runs in a Microsoft Failover Cluster with the backend being an EMC Fibre Channel SAN.  We've been pretty solid on the hardware side.  It's this "simple" software problem that's killing it.

Comment: Also not a real answer but maybe you could periodically save the active state and just prepare for the worst? That would anyway be a desired behavior to handle any unexpected server crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question: https://serverfault.com/questions/34427/windows-service-dependencies on ServerFault should answer your own. It links to this article: http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2008/02/04/ws2008-service-shutdown-and-crash-handling.aspx, which should help you get pre-shutdown notification and service shutdown ordering.

Comment: I've configured my service for pre-shutdown notification in the registry, but I can't figure out how to register for PRESHUTDOWN notification in a C# .NET NT Service.  I tried to p/invoke SetServiceStatus with the struct set for ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN either but it's not having any affect, or I can't get that event via OnCustomCommand.

Comment: The question is: when do you call SetServiceStatus ? The problem is that ServiceBase does it right when OnStart returns (in order to tell the SCM that the service state is RUNNING) with its own notion of accepted commands. So, I guess you need to spawn a thread from OnStart (which I guess you already do) and call SetServiceStatus again yourself with your own list of accepted commands.